# How to escape {{ or }} in django template?

Tags: python, django

Django treats `{{ var }}` as some variable in its template. How can I escape `{{ var }}` or `{{` or `}}` such that django does not treat it as variable.

`<p>"{{ some text }}"</p>` Should prints exactly the same.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`templatetag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) template tag.

As the linked-to doc states,

> Since the template system has no concept of "escaping", to display one of the bits used in template tags, you must use the `{% templatetag %}` tag.

For example:

```
<p>"{% templatetag openvariable %} some text {% templatetag closevariable %}"</p>
```

will appear as so:

```
<p>"{{ some text }}"</p>
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Why django doc don't mentions templatetag in [limitations-with-string-literals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#limitations-with-string-literals); 2. What can I do if I want to escape with template filter?

Answer (score 156):

Django 1.5 introduced [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-verbatim) template tag. It stops template from parsing contents of this tag:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{ var }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

will be rendered as:

```
{{ var }}
```

Comment: This is the most straight-forward way. +1

Comment: While 'verbatim' is generally useful, Django bug https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23424 makes it problematic for this specific usage. For example this fails:

{% verbatim %}{{{%endverbatim%}hello{% verbatim%}}}{% endverbatim %}

The word 'verbatim' will actually appear in the rendered text...

Answer (score 28):

**Edit:** I don't really recommended this because it's not very clean, but it's still an option.

I was searching for one that I could use with JQuery Templates and figured a way to do it without tags or filters. This is as short as I could get it:

```
{{ "{{ any text }" }}}
```

Is printed as:

```
{{ any text }}
```

**Why it works?** Any text within {{}} is displayed as is, as long as it doesn't have two closing braces }} in a row. Then there are three brackets in a row, django interprets two first ones as end of the variable leaving one additional closing brace.

Answer (score 15):

You can try escaping with html character escapes like:

{ = `&#123;`

} = `&#125;`

```
<p>"&#123;&#123; some text &#125;&#125;"</p>
```

---

## Update

In case anyone is trying to use the actual tags for javascript, [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) is a better solution:

> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag.

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 7):

if you simply need to use {{  }} as a variable for template framework like angularjs, then following maybe simpler:

in your `<app path>/templatetags/ngvar.py` , add

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def ngvar(var_name):
    return "{{%s}}" % var_name
```

and in template, do

```
{% load ngvar %}
{% ngvar "variable name" %}
```

if ngvar.py is the first template tag, then make sure to add `__init__.py` file to the `templatetags` directory

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to add a [word joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm) (zero width no-break space) between each curly bracket:

```
<p>"{&#8288;{ some text }&#8288;}"</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the above answers can solve the original problem, I add some hack around here for those who are scratching their heads like me.

Some times, we want to render a single brace followed by a variable. For example, in BibTeX, there may be something look like this:

```
@MISC{hu2012-spectral,
    author = {Hu, Pili},
    title = {Spectral Clustering Survey},
    howpublished = {GitHub, https://github.com/hupili/tutorial/tree/master/spectral-clustering},
    month = {May},
    year = {2012}
}
```

Those bib fields come from template variables. If you write

```
title = {{{title}}},
```

jinja can not compile and raise an error. If you write

```
title = { {{title}} },
```

there will be extra blanks. The hack around is to store '{' and '}' as variables and use later.

```
{% set lb = '{' %}
{% set rb = '}' %}
...
@MISC{{lb}}{{ meta.bib_key }},
    author = {{lb}}Hu, Pili{{rb}},
    title = {{lb}}{{ meta.title }}{{rb}},
    howpublished = {{lb}}GitHub, https://github.com/hupili/tutorial/tree/master/{{ auto.path}}{{rb}},
    month = {{lb}}{{ meta.month }}{{rb}},
    year = {{lb}}{{ meta.year }}{{rb}}
}
```

This looks clumsy but it is the best I find so far. If you have a cleaner solution, please tell me.

Comment: Note that the HTML entity mentioned above does not apply here. We want the raw text '{' in BiBTeX DB, instead of a '{' viewed from browser.

Comment: Nice - I made a property in my Model where I return the variable as a latexconform string e.g. return '{Author}'

Answer (score 2):

[This template tag](https://gist.github.com/629508) (designed for use with jQuery Templates) might do the trick. It let's you wrap content you don't want Django to interpret as variables with a template tag.

Answer (score 2):

it can be solved by avoing adjacent angular backets, if its inside javascript code then you can write

```
'{'+'{address.'+key+'}}'
```

I used this to print jinja variables into another template,using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja, which is what is being used for the templates, offers several suggestions for escaping [here.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping) What has worked best for me is using something like `"{% raw %}{{ some text }}{% endraw %}"`