# including handlebars templates within a django generated page

Tags: python, django, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using django to serve a page that includes a handlebars template. Mixing server and client side templating creates some ambiguity. If I have a template

```
<script id="my-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p> {{clientSideContent}} </p>
</script>
```

How can I tell the django templating engine that the `{{clientSideContent}}` tag isn't intended for it (since django and handlebars use the same tags)? Is there a raw strings tag in django, or an alternate good way to address this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem

https://gist.github.com/ericflo/629508

so use something like

```
{% verbatim %} {{clientSideContent}} {% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never versions of django (starting from version 1.5) have support for the [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-verbatim) tag:

So something like this should work:

```
<script id="my-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {% verbatim %}
  <p> {{clientSideContent}} </p>
  {% endverbatim %}
</script>
```

Hope it helps.