# Django preload Yelp API results

Tags: python, django

I am making a website for a restaurant and they want to show their Yelp reviews. I configured and can retrieve data with the Yelp API. I have to query two things in order to get what I need. All in all this means the page takes 10-15 seconds to load, and I don't want to have to query the Yelp API everytime someone wants to see the page anyway.

```
yelp_api = YelpAPI('secretkey1', 'secretkey2')
business_results = yelp_api.business_query(id='secretbuisness', location='secretplace')
reviews_results = yelp_api.reviews_query(id='secretbuisness', location='secretplace')
return render(request, 'reviews.html', {'reviews_results': reviews_results, 'business_results': business_results})
```

Is there any way to make it so I can get the Yelp API data separate from the page request and store it somewhere ready to use, maybe updating every 5-10 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use background task to do this.

1. Choose one of the background task django apps:

   - [Django Background Tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks) (easy setup, easy use, not very feature rich but good for your problem)
   - [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (feature rich, advanced setup, advanced use)
2. Make models for the results to store them in the database
3. Make an api request in an background task every hour or so and store the results in the models you created.
4. Show the results of the models in the html.

Alternatively you could do this in the html asynchronously with ajax (javascript).
So on the page, where you want to show the results, you could do an ajax request with javascript to the [rest api of yelp](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3) and render the whole data with something like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or other javascript rendering engines. Pay attention if you mix javascript template engines and django template syntax because django will probably render the javascript template. Here is the solution therefore: [How to escape {{ or }} in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template)