# Unable to use double braces to resolve variables

Tags: html, angularjs, django

I am unable to use double braces to resolve variables. Here's my js code.

```
var app = angular.module('toDo',[]);
app.controller('toDoController', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/todo/api/').then(function(response) {
    $scope.todoList = response.data;
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>To Do List</title>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/todo.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="toDo" ng-controller="toDoController">
        <h1>Todo List</h1>

        <form ng-submit="add()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" placeholder="Add a new todo task...">
            <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div ng-repeat="todo in todoList">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done"><a ng-href="/todo/api/{{todo.id}}" ng-bind="todo.task"></a>
        </div>

        <p>
            <button class="delete" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
            <button class="update" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
        </p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/todo.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

tasks which displayed in screen should redirect me to the url "/todo/api/". But values given in the braces not resolving it's ID. Currently the hyperlink redirecting always to the url "/todo/api/".

Kindly let me know if I am doing anything wrong or help me to fix this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are interpreted by the Django template renderer. You can use [**`{% verbatim %}`…`{% endverbatim %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to avoid interpreting the double curly brackets, like:

```
<a {% verbatim %}ng-href="/todo/api/{{todo.id}}"{% endverbatim %} ng-bind="todo.task"></a>
```

Comment: Is there any way, If I want to use inside django template? For example: `{% verbatim %} ng-href="{% url 'something' todo.id %}" {% endverbatim %}` Expecting to resolve `/<django url>/<js variable>`

Comment: @RajkumarSrinivasan: you should only use `{% verbatim %}`...`{% endverbatim %}` where you do *not* want the render to interpret the curly brackets. But you can not combine such URLs, no, since these are solved by the *backend*, not the *frontend*. The front end is not aware of the urls in the backend.