# Django template run {{ }} without execute

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In django template I write `<p>"{{sometext}}"</>p`. But when it is executed it convert like `<p>""</p>`. How to avoid this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape {{ or }} in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template)

Comment: What happens when you rewrite your line of template code as this: `<p>"{{ sometext }}"</p>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the [**`{% verbatim %}…{% endverbatim %}`** template tags [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to turn of interpolation locally:

```
{% verbatim %}<p>"{{sometext}}"</p>{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <p>" &#123;&#123; sometext &#125;&#125; " </p>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.