# Vue script in my django project is not showing up

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs3

I currently nearly finished a django project. On top of it, I just want to use vue to spare some repetition and discover some features that might better the user interaction experience. I referenced vue through CDN link in my base template `<scriptsrc="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>`.
And under the link, I tried a demo vue code

```
<script>
    const { createApp, ref } = Vue
  
    createApp({
      setup() {
        const notice = ref('Hello vue!')
        return {
          notice
        }
      }
    }).mount('#app')
  </script>
```

On top of my template I added `<div id="app">{{notice}} something</div>`.

I expect the top of my website to show a "hello vue! something", meaning vue is running properly. But I only get "something". Is CDN way of linking vue not acceptable to django or something else I misdid during the process that makes my vue demo code not working?

Comment: I _think_ you're being bitten by the fact that in Django, double curly braces are part of the Django template... so what gets sent to the client for vue has the {{notice}} stripped out (this also assumes scriptsrc vs script src is a typo in your question and not in your original).  I'd suggest:
A) Doing View Source to verify if {{notice}} was sent literally
B) Using Network Tools to determine if the CDN vue is getting pulled down
C) Consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template for how to correctly do this.

Comment: Hi Foon, thanks for replying! Yes, that script src is a type which is set properly in my original code. I checked page source and in that div section the variable place is empty, as if nothings there. I also used network tool, vue is requested, as i could see the source code of vue.global.js. As for the question u referenced, it's talking about treating {{}} literally, which is not what I'm looking for. I wish the template can retrieve variable/data from vue script. I tried and it literally print "{{notice}}" on the page :(

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comment, wrapping the curly braces that Vue uses with verbatim tag (so Django doesn't consume them as part of its templating) so the template is:

```
<div id="app">{% verbatim %}{{notice}}{% endverbatim%} something</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
    const { createApp, ref } = Vue
  
    createApp({
      setup() {
        const notice = ref('Hello vue!')
        return {
          notice
        }
      }
    }).mount('#app')
  </script>
```

as a template renders:

`Hello vue! something`